# Nested CollectionView not setting Data Source or Delegate properly?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have a collectionView setup like so:

```
class TagViewController: UIViewController,  UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout, UICollectionViewDataSource, SNPostViewCellDelegate {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        collectionView.delegate = self
        timeline.delegate = self
        UserService.posts(for: User.current,tagString: self.tagTitle!) { (postStuff) in
            let posts = postStuff.0
            self.postIds = postStuff.1
            self.posts = posts.sorted(by: {
                $0.timeStamp.compare($1.timeStamp) == .orderedAscending
            })
            self.timeline.dataSource = self
            self.collectionView.dataSource = self
            //self.timeline.collectionViewLayout.invalidateLayout()
        }
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        if collectionView == self.collectionView {
            return posts.count
        } else if collectionView == self.timeline {
            let first = posts.first?.timeStamp
            let last = posts.last?.timeStamp
            let months = last?.months(from: first!) ?? 0
            print("no of months",months)

            if let diff = last?.months(from: first!), diff <= 5 {
                return months + 5-diff
            } else {
                return months + 1
            }
        } else {
            preconditionFailure("Unknown collection view!")
        }
    }
  func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        if collectionView == self.collectionView {
            let post = posts[indexPath.row]
            let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! SNPostViewCell
            cell.isVideo = post.isVideo
            cell.delegate = self
            cell.notes.text = post.notes
            cell.thumbnailURL = URL(string: post.thumbnailURL)
            let formatter = DateFormatter()
            formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
            cell.timeStampLabel.text = formatter.string(from: post.timeStamp)
            cell.mediaURL = URL(string: post.mediaURL)
            cell.notes.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cell.thumbnail.bottomAnchor,constant: 0.0).isActive = true
            return cell
        } else if collectionView == self.timeline {
            let index = indexPath.row
            print(index,"index")
            let calendar = Calendar.current
            let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
            dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MMM"
            let firstPost = posts.first?.timeStamp
            let month = calendar.date(byAdding: .month, value: index, to: firstPost!)
            let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "SNMonthViewCell", for: indexPath) as! SNMonthViewCell
            cell.monthLabel.text = dateFormatter.string(from: month!)
            cell.monthLabel.textAlignment = .center
            return cell
        } else {
            preconditionFailure("Unknown collection view!")
        }
    }
```

As you can see once my posts are loaded, I set the dataSource of my timeline collectionView - the timeline is what I am interested as this is what contains the nested subcollectionView. Basically how it works is each SNMonthViewCell is labeled with a month - Jan for instance, then inside the cell, a nested sub collection contains a cell for each day of jan. Now to set the delegate/data sources for this days collectionView in the month cell, I do:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView,
                             willDisplay cell: UICollectionViewCell,
                             forItemAt indexPath: IndexPath){
    if collectionView == self.timeline{
        guard let monthViewCell = cell as? SNMonthViewCell else  {
            return
        }
        let index = indexPath.item
        let firstPost = self.posts.first?.timeStamp
        let monthDate = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .month, value: index, to: firstPost!)
        let monthInt = Calendar.current.component(.month, from: monthDate!)
        let yearInt = Calendar.current.component(.year, from: monthDate!)
        let postDates = dates(self.posts, withinMonth: monthInt, withinYear: yearInt)
        let dayDelegatesInstance = dayCellDelegates(firstDay: (monthDate?.startOfMonth())!, monthPosts:postDates)
        monthViewCell.setCollectionViewDataSourceDelegate(dataSourceDelegate: dayDelegatesInstance)
    }
}

class dayCellDelegates: NSObject,UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate {
    let firstDay: Date
    let monthPosts: [Post]

    init(firstDay: Date, monthPosts: [Post]){
        self.firstDay = firstDay
        self.monthPosts = monthPosts
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView,
                        numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        print("how many cells?")
        let range = Calendar.current.range(of: .day, in: .month, for: self.firstDay)!
        return range.count
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView,
                        cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        print("looking for cell!")
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "dayCell",
                                                      for: indexPath as IndexPath)
        let components: Set<Calendar.Component> = [.day]
        //let contained = self.postDates.reduce(false,{Calendar.current.dateComponents(components, from: $0).day == indexPath.item})
        let filtered = self.monthPosts.filter { (post) -> Bool in
            Calendar.current.dateComponents(components, from: post.timeStamp).day == indexPath.item
        }
        if filtered.isEmpty == true {
            cell.backgroundColor = UIColor(red:0.15, green:0.67, blue:0.93, alpha:1.0)
        }
        return cell
    }
}
```

You can see that I use my external class dayCellDelegates to set the delegates for this subcollectionView. Now In the SNMonthViewCell I referred to before, I set the datasource and delegate like so:

```
class SNMonthViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {

    @IBOutlet private weak var dayTicks: UICollectionView!

    @IBOutlet weak var monthLabel: UILabel!

    func setCollectionViewDataSourceDelegate
        <D: UICollectionViewDataSource & UICollectionViewDelegate>
        (dataSourceDelegate: D) {
        dayTicks.delegate = dataSourceDelegate
        dayTicks.dataSource = dataSourceDelegate
        dayTicks.reloadData()
    }
}
```

Awesome... HOWEVER, the delegate methods for my subcollectionView are never called. How do I know? Because those first print statements I put in the first two methods are never called....

What does my timeline look like?

[image]

Somehow just one month shoes up and none of the day cells get drawn. I think largely because these delegate and data source methods are not being used to drawn them. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: if there are votes to close I would love to know why. I am happy to improve the question in some way to make it better

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's have a look what's happening when you setting dataSource and delegate to `SNMonthViewCell` cell

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView,
    willDisplay cell: UICollectionViewCell,
    forItemAt indexPath: IndexPath){
    if collectionView == self.timeline{
        ...
        let dayDelegatesInstance = dayCellDelegates(firstDay: (monthDate?.startOfMonth())!, monthPosts:postDates)
        monthViewCell.setCollectionViewDataSourceDelegate(dataSourceDelegate: dayDelegatesInstance)
    }
}
```

you instanciate `dayCellDelegates` object, set it to your cell and that's all. `dayCellDelegates` will be deallocated on function exit.

Simple what do you need to do, it's save references to your `dayCellDelegates` objects, so they will not be deallocated. You can to it in different ways, but I suggest to use Dictionary.

First, you need to create property `private var dataSources: [IndexPath : dayCellDelegates] = [:]` in your TagViewController class. Now when `willDisplay` method will be called you need to save your `dayCellDelegates` object into dictionary

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView,
    willDisplay cell: UICollectionViewCell,
    forItemAt indexPath: IndexPath){
    if collectionView == self.timeline{
        guard let monthViewCell = cell as? SNMonthViewCell else  {
            return
        }
        let index = indexPath.item
        let firstPost = self.posts.first?.timeStamp
        let monthDate = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .month, value: index, to: firstPost!)
        let monthInt = Calendar.current.component(.month, from: monthDate!)
        let yearInt = Calendar.current.component(.year, from: monthDate!)
        let postDates = dates(self.posts, withinMonth: monthInt, withinYear: yearInt)
        let dayDelegatesInstance = dayCellDelegates(firstDay: (monthDate?.startOfMonth())!, monthPosts:postDates)
        dataSources[indexPath] = dayDelegatesInstance
        monthViewCell.setCollectionViewDataSourceDelegate(dataSourceDelegate: dayDelegatesInstance)
    }
}
```

However, you will rewrite your delegate each time when method will be called. To fix that, you need to check if `dayCellDelegates` was previously saved

```
if let dayDelegatesInstance = dataSources[indexPath] {
    monthViewCell.setCollectionViewDataSourceDelegate(dataSourceDelegate: dayDelegatesInstance)
} else {
    let dayDelegatesInstance = dayCellDelegates(firstDay: (monthDate?.startOfMonth())!, monthPosts:postDates)
        dataSources[indexPath] = dayDelegatesInstance
        monthViewCell.setCollectionViewDataSourceDelegate(dataSourceDelegate: dayDelegatesInstance)
}
```

Comment: thanks! Is there a typo? `Shouldn't dayCellDelegates[indexPath] = dayDelegatesInstance` be `dataSources[indexPath] = dayDelegatesInstance`? Also now I am getting print statements to execute in the dayCellDelegates method numberOfItemsInSection but not in cellForItemAt. Any idea why that might be?

Comment: yes, it was a typo, sorry for that. Do you have any items to show? `cellForItemAt ` will not be called, if `numberOfItemsInSection ` return 0

Comment: numberOfItemsInSection is returning the correct numbers- it prints out 30,31,30,31,30 for range.count which is the number of days in a month. There are 5 months (the parent collectionView) so I think this makes sense. However anything I try and do in cellForItemAt in the dayCellDelegates (should find 1 cell at each of the 31, 30 days for instance... does not execute (print statements, etc)